# How to remove a profile in aws-vault

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have used `aws-vault add production` to create a temporary credentials. Because there is no *production* named profile in *.aws/credentials* I decided to remove the credentials and configure a new one, with corrected name. For that I used `aws-vault remove production`. That of course only deleted the credentials, but not the profile name shown in the `aws-vault list` command output. Is there a way to delete that profile name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profiles you see in `aws-vault list` correspond to profiles defined in your `~/.aws/config` file. To remove a profile, edit `~/.aws/config` and remove it.  E.g., if I see:

```
$ aws-vault list
Profile                     Credentials                 Sessions                         
=======                     ===========                 ========                         
production                  production                  -                                
testing                     -                           -
```

Then in `~/.aws/config` I will find:

```
[profile production]

[profile testing]
```

And if I remove the entry for `[profile testing]`, I no longer see it in the output of `aws-vault list`:

```
$ aws-vault list
Profile                     Credentials                 Sessions                         
=======                     ===========                 ========                         
production                  production                  -
```

---

Here's a complete walkthrough to make sure we're both seeing the same behavior.

1. I start with an empty credentials list:

   ```
   $ aws-vault list
   Profile                  Credentials              Sessions
   =======                  ===========              ========
   ```
2. I add `production` credentials:

   ```
   $ aws-vault add production
   Enter Access Key ID: example
   Enter Secret Access Key:
   Added credentials to profile "production" in vault
   ```

   Which now appear in the list:

   ```
   $ aws-vault list
   Profile                  Credentials              Sessions
   =======                  ===========              ========
   production               production               -
   ```

   This creates a profile entry in `~/.aws/config`:

   ```
   $ cat ~/.aws/config
   [profile production]
   ```
3. If I remove those credentials:

   ```
   $ aws-vault remove production
   Delete credentials for profile "production"? (y|N) y
   Deleted credentials.
   ```

   The profile still shows up in the list even though the credentials have been deleted:

   ```
   $ aws-vault list
   Profile                  Credentials              Sessions
   =======                  ===========              ========
   production               -                        -
   ```
4. If I remove the `[profile production]` entry from `~/.aws/config`:

   ```
   $ sed -i '/profile production/d' ~/.aws/config
   ```

   Then the profile no longer appears in the output of `aws-vault list`:

   ```
   $ aws-vault list
   Profile                  Credentials              Sessions
   =======                  ===========              ========
   ```

Comment: larsks, thanks. the problem is when I added production credentials to aws-vault (the same one that corresponds to name.production profile from ~/.aws/config) it didn't create a new profile inside ~/.aws/config, so there is nothing to be deleted there. try aws-vault add something (this something should not exist in the ~/.aws/config) and see what happens.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a complete example of the behavior I'm seeing while trying this out locally. When I'm using `aws-vault`, (a) adding credentials creates a profile in `~/.aws/config` if it doesn't already exist, and (b) removing that profile entry prevents it from showing up in the output of `aws-vault list`.

Comment: Hi larsks, I have found a solution for that particular situation. It's in the answer below. Anyhow, thank you for the effort, and for a showcase of how that should function in general.

Comment: Hi larsks, I deleted my answer - you are right, you already answered. Somehow all the time I was thinking that you are deleting from the credentials files, and not config. My mistake. Sorry about that.